# Trend Survey Statistical Tests

Tags: statistical-significance, survey, likert, trend

I am designing a trend survey using a Likert style survey.  I have three opinion questions, each with the same choice of responses ranging from Not Likely to Very Likely. Are there any statistical tests I could use to analyze this data?